# Why is my program accessing values of the binaryString array when I try to print "value"?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void MakeBinaryString(char *outString, char valueToConvert)
{
    // Convert a 1-byte value to a string that shows its value in
    // binary. We do this by checking to see each bit is on and
    // if it is, setting the character value to '1' or '0' if not.
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        // Is the bit a 1?

        // The shifting is needed to quickly generate a power of 2
        // so that we check only 1 bit at a time, starting with bit 7 // and working its way down.
        if (valueToConvert & (1 << (7 - i)))
            outString[i] = '1';
        else
            outString[i] = '0';
    }
    outString[8] = '\0';
}
int main(void)
{
    char value = 5;
    char binaryString[6];
    MakeBinaryString(binaryString, value);
    printf("The binary equivalent of %d is %s\n", value, binaryString);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: The binary equivalent of 48 is 00000101

So the above code can be fixed if we increase size of binaryString array to 9. But I don't understand why value is being printed as 48. If I comment out the else block of MakeBinaryString then value is printed as 5. But with the else block, whatever value I set char value to, it is printing 48 or 49.

Comment: `binaryString` has 6 elements. You are accessing 8

Comment: Accessing arrays out-of-bounds results in undefined behavior, anything could happen.

Comment: `'0' == 48`. `'1' == 49`.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* can cause a lot of weird things, such as this

Comment: Thanks but I'm aware of that. This is a debugging question indeed. I'm confused about why is "value" being printed as 48 instead of 5.

Comment: Because when you write outside the bounds of `binaryString`, it's overflowing into the memory for `value`

Comment: Because you overwrote it with `outString[i] = '0';` which in ASCII is `48`. The out-of-bounds access damages *something*, and here it was `char value`. It could have been anything, or harmless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you show, you're writing outside the bounds of `binaryString`, accessing 9 elements when there are only 6. This invokes undefined behaviour, anything could happen.

The reason that you see `48` or `49` in *this particular case* is that memory *just so happens* to be laid out such that the out-of-bounds writes are corrupting `value`.

The numeric ASCII values of `'0'` and `'1'` are `48` and `49`, respectively. When you write out of bounds, you're overwriting `value` with one of those.

---

It's important to note that what you're doing isn't allowed, and could lead to any behaviour. You just got lucky in that variables are organized on the stack in such a way that the only *noticeable* damage is to `value`. Building for a different platform, with a different compiler or with different compiler options, or adding more to the program could lead to different and arbitrary results, including (but not limited to) crashes and corruption of other data used in the program.